# Is there code or framework to simultaneously handle TPL and Asynch/Await?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

In my scenario, I have a console program that will be running queries simultaneously against 600-800 production databases. The machine it is running on has 16 cores that can all be used simultaneously via TPL. How can I also get performance improvements by using async-await techniques as well. The 600-800 databases are across 30 different servers, so ideally I would like to throw as many simultaneous queries as possible. While processing, I would expect each core to be running between 70-90% utilization. I can get to those utilization numbers using async-await. I can get to the 16 cores processing using TPL. I am not sure how to combine both techniques to achieve maximum throughput.

Comment: How do you plan to use the results of queries? If you just want to query the servers without future processing of results I thing your bottleneck can be on another 30 servers.

Comment: We are creating a Data Dictionary across all system databases. Essentially, we will have separate queries that will be issues against each server.  We will also have queries issues against each database.   Each type of query will return result sets that will be stored in a centralized metadata repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TPL Dataflow. The TPL `async`-ready actor library.

You simply need to create an `ActionBlock` and set its parallelism degree, preferably through a configuration file that you can tweak in production. CPU intensive work should be limited to about the number of cores. The limit for I/O intensive work can be much higher. You need to see what works best in your specific scenario.

You define an action, that can also be async, and post items to run the action on them. These items can be delegates, or command objects for example:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Command>(
    command => command.ExecuteAsync(),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1000});

foreach (var command in GenerateCommands())
{
    block.Post(command);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```